# Retrieve data from two different data into RecyclerView in Android

Tags: android

How can I retrieve the data from two different parents into recyclerview?
the food detail is retrieve from Food table, but the username have to retrieve from User table.

[image]

[image]

Here is my code for the Homefragment.

```
package com.example.user8.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
//    ListView listView;
//    DatabaseReference db;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private List<Food> result;
private foodadapter adapter;

private FirebaseDatabase database;
private DatabaseReference ref;

public HomeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    ref = database.getReference("Food");

    result = new ArrayList<>();

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.food_list);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager lim = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    lim.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(lim);

    adapter = new foodadapter(result);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    updateList();
    return v;
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case 0:
            removeFood(item.getItemId());
            break;

        case 1:
            changeFood(item.getItemId());
            break;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}

private int getItemIndex(Food food){
    int index = -1;
    for(int i = 0; i < result.size();i++)
    {
        if (result.get(i).key.equals(food.key))
        {
            index = i;
            break;
        }

    }
    return index;
}

private void updateList() {

    ref.orderByChild("status").equalTo("AVAILABLE").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            result.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(Food.class));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Food model = dataSnapshot.getValue(Food.class);

            int index = getItemIndex(model);

            result.set(index,model);
            adapter.notifyItemChanged(index);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Food model = dataSnapshot.getValue(Food.class);

            int index = getItemIndex(model);

            result.remove(index);
            adapter.notifyItemRemoved(index);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

private void removeFood(int pos){
    Food food = result.get(pos);
    food.status="nono";

    Map<String,Object> foodValue = food.toMap();
    Map<String,Object> newFood = new HashMap<>();

    newFood.put(food.key,foodValue);

    ref.updateChildren(newFood);
}

private void changeFood(int pos){
    ((Activity) getContext()).closeContextMenu();
}

}
```

removeFood is the method to update the status of the food.
changeFood is the method to close the contextMenu.

Here is the foodadapter.java

```
package com.example.user8.myapplication;

import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;

public class foodadapter extends         RecyclerView.Adapter<foodadapter.foodviewholder>{

private List<Food>list;

public foodadapter(List<Food> list) {
    this.list = list;
}

@Override
public foodviewholder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v;
    v = LayoutInflater.
            from(parent.getContext()).
            inflate(R.layout.view_item,parent,false);
    final foodviewholder vHolder = new foodviewholder(v);

    return vHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final foodviewholder holder, final int position) {
    Food food = list.get(position);

    holder.txtname.setText(food.u_food);
    holder.txtdate.setText(food.u_date);
    holder.txttime.setText(food.u_time);

    holder.itemView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(new View.OnCreateContextMenuListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu contextMenu, View view, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo contextMenuInfo) {
            contextMenu.setHeaderTitle("Select choice.");
            contextMenu.add(holder.getAdapterPosition(),0,0,"Request");
            contextMenu.add(holder.getAdapterPosition(),1,0,"Cancel");
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

public class foodviewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView txtname,txtdate,txttime;

    public foodviewholder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        txtname = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_food);
        txtdate = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_date);
        txttime = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_time);
    }
}
}
```

Here is my Food.java

```
package com.example.user8.myapplication;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Food
{
    public String     uid,u_food,u_date,u_time,status,u_postdate,key,uid_request;

    public Food(String uid, String u_food, String u_date, String u_time,     String u_postdate, String status, String key, String uid_request)
{
    this.uid = uid;
    this.u_food = u_food;
    this.u_date = u_date;
    this.u_time = u_time;
    this.u_postdate = u_postdate;
    this.status = status;
    this.key = key;
    this.uid_request = uid_request;
}

public Map<String,Object> toMap(){
    HashMap<String,Object> result = new HashMap<>();
    result.put("uid",uid);
    result.put("u_food",u_food);
    result.put("u_time",u_time);
    result.put("u_date",u_date);
    result.put("u_postdate",u_postdate);
    result.put("status",status);
    result.put("key",key);
    result.put("uid_request",uid_request);

    return  result;
}

public String getUid_request() {
    return uid_request;
}

public void setUid_request(String uid_request) {
    this.uid_request = uid_request;
}

public String getKey() {
    return key;
}

public void setKey(String key) {
    this.key = key;
}

public String getUid() {
    return uid;
}

public void setUid(String uid) {
    this.uid = uid;
}

public String getU_food() {
    return u_food;
}

public void setU_food(String u_food) {
    this.u_food = u_food;
}

public String getU_date() {
    return u_date;
}

public void setU_date(String u_date) {
    this.u_date = u_date;
}

public String getU_time() {
    return u_time;
}

public void setU_time(String u_time) {
    this.u_time = u_time;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getU_postdate() {
    return u_postdate;
}

public void setU_postdate(String u_postdate) {
    this.u_postdate = u_postdate;
}

Food(){}

}
```

Comment: attach code which you are using to fetch data from firebase so that i can make modifications in your code.

Comment: So is the question about trying to display two different types of items in the `RecyclerView` list?

Comment: I think is different parent? data that retrieve from Food table and Users table.

Comment: @shinmin provide your Food class also.

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code i have supposed that you have your Food model class something like

```
public class Food{
   String key,status,u_id,u_date...;
   User user;//this is supposed to be another model class 
}
public class User {
      String u_email,u_imageURL,u_username;
}
```

So after getting single child of Food we need to call  `fetchUserDetail(Food model,int index)` which will fetch the user data and reflect it to the food object at given index.

```
package com.example.user8.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
//    ListView listView;
//    DatabaseReference db;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private List<Food> result;
private foodadapter adapter;

private FirebaseDatabase database;
private DatabaseReference ref;

public HomeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    ref = database.getReference("Food");

    result = new ArrayList<>();

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.food_list);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager lim = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    lim.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(lim);

    adapter = new foodadapter(result);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    updateList();
    return v;
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case 0:
            removeFood(item.getItemId());
            break;

        case 1:
            changeFood(item.getItemId());
            break;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}

private int getItemIndex(Food food){
    int index = -1;
    for(int i = 0; i < result.size();i++)
    {
        if (result.get(i).key.equals(food.key))
        {
            index = i;
            break;
        }

    }
    return index;
}

private void updateList() {

    ref.orderByChild("status").equalTo("AVAILABLE").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            result.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(Food.class));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Food model = dataSnapshot.getValue(Food.class);

            int index = getItemIndex(model);

            result.set(index,model);
            adapter.notifyItemChanged(index);
            //now make a firebase request to fetch user data based on uid
            fetchUserDetail(model,index);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Food model = dataSnapshot.getValue(Food.class);

            int index = getItemIndex(model);

            result.remove(index);
            adapter.notifyItemRemoved(index);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
private void fetchUserDetail(Food model,int index) {
ref = database.getReference("Users");
    ref.child(model.getUId()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            // TODO: handle the user
             result.get(index).setUser(dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        // Getting Post failed, log a message
        Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        // ...
    }
});

}

private void removeFood(int pos){
    Food food = result.get(pos);
    food.status="nono";

    Map<String,Object> foodValue = food.toMap();
    Map<String,Object> newFood = new HashMap<>();

    newFood.put(food.key,foodValue);

    ref.updateChildren(newFood);
}

private void changeFood(int pos){
    ((Activity) getContext()).closeContextMenu();
}

}
```